# Apply-templates with different modes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, mode

I want to process nodes with apply-templates but use different modes to match the right template-rules for all the nodes within the sequence.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<story>
    <p class="h1">
        <content>heading</content>
        <br/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <content>some text</content>
        <br/>
        <content>more text...</content>
    </p>
</story>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="div">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@class='h1'">
                <xsl:element name="h1">
                    <!--apply-tempaltes mode:#default, for br mode:ignore-->
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="p">
                    <!--apply-tempaltes mode:#default-->
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="content" mode="#default">
        <xsl:element name="span">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="br" mode="#default">
        <xsl:element name="br"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="br" mode="ignore"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Wanted Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<story>
    <h1 class="h1"><span>heading</span>    
    </h1>
    <p><span>some text</span> 
        <br/>
        <span>more text...</span> 
    </p>
</story>
```

XSLT-version is 2.0. I know, there are other ways to achieve the wanted output for this example, but i would like to use the mode-attributes.

Comment: You haven't told us what the wanted output is. Shall we read your mind? I have no idea what this means: _"apply-tempaltes mode:#default, for br mode:#ignore"_. You need to tell us what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to know, if i can use different modes for all the items in a sequence. `#default` will will not work, as soon as i use mode `ignore`. i could go with `mode="#all"` for template `match="content"`. I'm sure, there is a better solution.

Comment: Still unclear, please tell us about the _goal_ instead of asking about modes. Do you want to ignore (that is: not copy to the result document) `br` elements if they are inside a `p[@class = 'h1']` element?

Comment: ok maybe i chose a bad example. the goal is to process the items of `<xsl:apply-templates/>` with different modes, depending on their names. Yes, i want to ignore `br`elements but without using predicates in the match-pattern.

Comment: You can write two `xsl:apply-templates`, e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="node() except br"/>`, `<xsl:apply-templates select="br" mode="mode-name"/>`, only as you want to ignore the element you don't need the second apply-templates at all, applying only to `node() except br` suffices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAICT, you want to do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="#all">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[@class='h1']">
    <h1 class="h1">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="h1"/>
    </h1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="content" mode="#all">
    <span>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="br" mode="h1"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `mode="#all"` does the trick in this case, thanks. I assume, there is no way to process the items of a sequence with different modes depending on their names?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. Normally, a template matches nodes by their name, so there is no need for `mode` to do the same thing. You use `mode` when you have two templates with the same (or overlapping) match pattern. Note that the above could be achieved without using `mode`at all, just by `<xsl:template match="br[ancestor::p[@class='h1']]" />`.

Comment: I am not sure it matters for the task in the question, but the XSLT 2.0 identity transformation with modes requires an `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>` instead of `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>`, to work with any mode.

Comment: I mean: I want to match some of the items of the `apply-templates` sequence with templates mode="#default" (in this case `content`)  and some (in this case `br`) with a template mode="ignore". I also don't want to use predicates in the `<xsl:template match="br">`

Comment: @Ferestes You would have to issue two `xsl:apply-templates` instructions, with different modes and different select expressions. I don't think you will easily find an example where this would be a good solution (if only because it changes the order of the processed nodes).